# How do I selectively change numbers to subscript as part of chemical names?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find-and-replace

Sometimes I have to typeset, correct, or otherwise format papers by other people. These papers sometimes lack the proper formatting for chemical names. For example, H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> may have been written as H2O2. When this is done a few dozen times over the course of a document, manually changing these is a time sink.

Using Word's native search and replace function, how can I apply the subscript to all such instances within a document? Something on a per-word basis is acceptable. Using a unicode character for subscript 2 will not be acceptable. This should be achievable using normal subscript formatting applied selectively.

Is there a good write-up or one-stop guide on Word's regex-like features?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix the first instance so that it has subscript applied to numerals, then copy it.  In Word's find box, Find what: would be (for example) H2O2.  In the Replace with: box, you type ^c (or via Special button at bottom of dialog, you'll see an option for Clipboard Contents to insert ^c for you).

Since the last thing you copied was the correctly formatted chemical name, you can step through quickly and replace individually (or if you're confident, replace all).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA macro that automatically subscripts any numeric characters in the selected text.

```
Sub AutoSubscriptSelectedNumbers()
'
' AutoSubscriptSelectedNumbers Macro
' Subscript every numeric character in the selected text
'
For Each Char In Selection.Characters
    If IsNumeric(Char) Then
        Char.Font.Subscript = True
    End If
Next
End Sub
```